# Are these LEGO Star Wars bricks genuine or fake?

Tags: star-wars, clone-brands, accessories, ebay

I bought some LEGO pieces from eBay, and I'm not sure if they are genuine LEGO.

I compared them with my LEGO, and every piece of my LEGO has the logo ©LEGO on it. However, only some of the ones I bought have this logo, and some do not.

[image]

You can see the © symbol on the top gun, the bottom is a gun from my own LEGO collection. If you flip them over, my gun (bottom) has some numbers (I think manufacturing number) and the word LEGO on it.  The new one (top) has nothing. Is the top gun just an older LEGO, or a fake knockoff?

Additionally, some of the battledroid torsos have the © LEGO mark on them, as well as some numbers, and some of them have just © and nothing else.

[image]

It is the same with the battledroid heads. On the left, my genuine part has the ©LEGO and numbers on the other side.  On the new ones in question (right), there is nothing.

Comment: They seem legit to me.

Comment: the "SM##" on the left gun is the identification that BanBao or Sluban clones are using, don't remember exactly which, but definitely clones.

Comment: @RaduMaris the gun on the right is the suspected clone, so your comment is confusing

Comment: @GregChabala Misread there, now I'm also confused as I've got a BanBao/Sluban set from KFC (children menu) and all their parts had the SM## on them, while all my lego pieces have LEGO in front and plain numbers on back.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find an official source for this statement, but with the exclusion of a few rarities like test bricks, and perhaps a few other cases, every piece of genuine LEGO will have the brand stamped on it somewhere.

You've taken photos of pieces together that clearly ought to have come from the same mold, where one displays the LEGO brand and the other does not. That seems like solid proof that you've purchased fake parts to me.

As an example of how similar clone bricks can be, here are some battle droids made by LEPIN: https://cheap-bricks.com/lepin-05025-star-wars-homing-spider-droid/

[image: closeup of figures]

It's hard to see, but I can make out the © on the trigger of the stormtrooper's weapon.

Comment: The picture you posted is of actual Lego. Even though your link dosen't work, I found the exact picture on other listings for Lepin.  Closer examination shows that the pictures used on these sites selling Lepin are using pictures of actual Lego.  Lepin studs are blank, and you can almost make out the word LEGO in some of the pictures on studs.  Not really surprising as they already have proven they will stoop to any level to blatantly rip people off.

Comment: I can neither confirm nor refute your statement. As you allude to, this picture is from the official product images for the Lepin 05025 set. If they are using LEGO imagery to create their own product images, that's unfortunate. I don't own any Lepin to compare with myself. OP hasn't asked any further questions, I doubt any further effort on this question will be useful.

Comment: I simply wanted to clear any false information about the "C" blasters not being legitimate Lego for anyone searching for related information and ending up here.  Seeking information on Lego is what brought me to this site after all.  It actually surprised me that no one knew about the "C" version since they're only maybe 10? years old and common.  You can almost make out the LEGO logo on the battle droid chest and the Lego specific part number on their legs. xD

Answer (score 2):

The Star Wars blasters in question are real LEGO.  I grabbed a hand-full of Star Wars blasters from my collection and laid them out for comparison.  All of these came from sets I bought, brand new.  The "C" guns on the left outnumber the LEGO/part numbered version on the right.

[image]

[image]

Another hand-full of the short blasters yielded similar results, a lot of them being the "C" version.

I sorted through my battle droids and only some had "LEGO" stamped on their chest.  The ones without it had the "C" mark inside their mid-torso with the part number either on the left or right side of "C".  ALL versions had LEGO stamped inside their back stud.  All of the droids with the "C" torso had no markings on their necks. Only the droids with "LEGO" on their chest had necks with markings.  ALL droids had "LEGO" stamped on the rear of their legs under the clip. Some legs had the part number on the front, some did not.

[image]

[image]

For clarity and any doubts someone may have, here is a typical example taken from a site selling off-brand "Lego" sets using pictures of real Lego sets and pieces:

[image]

"HonestJay" indeed.

Answer (score 0):

These are most likely Lego. The similarities in the molding is far too similar for these to be fake (unless someone spent obscene amounts of time creating very accurate fakes). The most suspicious thing to me is the © on the trigger section of the rifle. Other than that, they are just too identical to be a knock-off.

Also, the sheen on the plastic seems appropriate. Maybe a little bit aged on the droid head in question, but they tend to dull with age anyway. These look to be genuine.